# java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/share/opensearch/data/nodes при открытии соединения между opensearch и opensearchdashboards

Tags: docker-compose, elasticsearch, permissions

Я пытаюсь создать opensearch serveur с помощью docker-compose. Он отлично работает на Fedora35, но не работает на Ubuntu 22.04. Я получаю сообщение об ошибке, говорящее, что OpenSearch не может создать или получить доступ к каталогу в `/usr/share/opensearch/data/nodes` due to an `AccessDeniedException`.

`docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: '3'
services:

  # Serveur OpenSearch (fork Elasticsearch 7.10)
  opensearch:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch:2.11.0
    container_name: opensearch
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - node.roles=ml, data, master, ingest
      - plugins.ml_commons.native_memory_threshold=100
      - plugins.security.disabled=true
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms4096m -Xmx4096m"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/opensearch/data:/usr/share/opensearch/data
    # command: bash -c "mkdir -p /usr/share/opensearch/data/nodes && chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/opensearch/data"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9600:9600
    networks:
      - opensearch-net
      
  # Opensearch dashboard pour la visualisation
  opensearch-dashboards:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch-dashboards:2.11.0
    container_name: opensearch-dashboards
    ports:
        - 5601:5601
    networks:
      - opensearch-net
    environment:
      - 'OPENSEARCH_HOSTS=["http://opensearch:9200"]'
      - "DISABLE_SECURITY_DASHBOARDS_PLUGIN=true"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/opensearch-dashboards/config/opensearch_dashboards.yml:/usr/share/opensearch-dashboards/config/opensearch_dashboards.yml
    depends_on:
      - opensearch

networks:
  opensearch-net:
    driver: bridge
```

Вот логи:

```
.venv) reply@reply-GP66-Leopard-11UH:~/Documents/chatbot-rag/docker-opensearch$ sudo docker-compose up
[+] Running 2/0
 ✔ Container opensearch             Running                                                                                                                                                            0.0s 
 ✔ Container opensearch-dashboards  Running                                                                                                                                                            0.0s 
Attaching to opensearch, opensearch-dashboards
opensearch             | Enabling execution of install_demo_configuration.sh for OpenSearch Security Plugin
opensearch             | **************************************************************************
opensearch             | ** This tool will be deprecated in the next major release of OpenSearch **
opensearch             | ** https://github.com/opensearch-project/security/issues/1755           **
opensearch             | **************************************************************************
opensearch             | OpenSearch Security Demo Installer
opensearch             |  ** Warning: Do not use on production or public reachable systems **
opensearch             | Basedir: /usr/share/opensearch
opensearch             | OpenSearch install type: rpm/deb on Amazon Linux release 2023 (Amazon Linux)
opensearch             | OpenSearch config dir: /usr/share/opensearch/config
opensearch             | OpenSearch config file: /usr/share/opensearch/config/opensearch.yml
opensearch             | OpenSearch bin dir: /usr/share/opensearch/bin
opensearch             | OpenSearch plugins dir: /usr/share/opensearch/plugins
opensearch             | OpenSearch lib dir: /usr/share/opensearch/lib
opensearch             | Detected OpenSearch Version: x-content-2.11.0
opensearch             | Detected OpenSearch Security Version: 2.11.0.0
opensearch             | 
opensearch             | ### Success
opensearch             | ### Execute this script now on all your nodes and then start all nodes
opensearch             | ### OpenSearch Security will be automatically initialized.
opensearch             | ### If you like to change the runtime configuration 
opensearch             | ### change the files in ../../../config/opensearch-security and execute: 
opensearch             | "/usr/share/opensearch/plugins/opensearch-security/tools/securityadmin.sh" -cd "/usr/share/opensearch/config/opensearch-security" -icl -key "/usr/share/opensearch/config/kirk-key.pem" -cert "/usr/share/opensearch/config/kirk.pem" -cacert "/usr/share/opensearch/config/root-ca.pem" -nhnv
opensearch             | ### or run ./securityadmin_demo.sh
opensearch             | ### To use the Security Plugin ConfigurationGUI
opensearch             | ### To access your secured cluster open https://<hostname>:<HTTP port> and log in with admin/admin.
opensearch             | ### (Ignore the SSL certificate warning because we installed self-signed demo certificates)
opensearch             | Enabling OpenSearch Security Plugin
opensearch             | Enabling execution of OPENSEARCH_HOME/bin/opensearch-performance-analyzer/performance-analyzer-agent-cli for OpenSearch Performance Analyzer Plugin
opensearch             | WARNING: A terminally deprecated method in java.lang.System has been called
opensearch             | WARNING: System::setSecurityManager has been called by org.opensearch.bootstrap.OpenSearch (file:/usr/share/opensearch/lib/opensearch-2.11.0.jar)
opensearch             | WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.opensearch.bootstrap.OpenSearch
opensearch             | WARNING: System::setSecurityManager will be removed in a future release
opensearch             | WARNING: A terminally deprecated method in java.lang.System has been called
opensearch             | WARNING: System::setSecurityManager has been called by org.opensearch.bootstrap.Security (file:/usr/share/opensearch/lib/opensearch-2.11.0.jar)
opensearch             | WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.opensearch.bootstrap.Security
opensearch             | WARNING: System::setSecurityManager will be removed in a future release
opensearch             | [2023-11-02T17:35:35,817][INFO ][o.o.n.Node               ] [05a295b38cbe] version[2.11.0], pid[105], build[tar/4dcad6dd1fd45b6bd91f041a041829c8687278fa/2023-10-13T02:55:55.511945994Z], OS[Linux/6.2.0-36-generic/amd64], JVM[Eclipse Adoptium/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/17.0.8/17.0.8+7]
opensearch             | [2023-11-02T17:35:35,819][INFO ][o.o.n.Node               ] [05a295b38cbe] JVM home [/usr/share/opensearch/jdk], using bundled JDK/JRE [true]
opensearch             | [2023-11-02T17:35:35,819][INFO ][o.o.n.Node               ] [05a295b38cbe] JVM arguments [-Xshare:auto, -Dopensearch.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Dopensearch.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.locale.providers=SPI,COMPAT, -Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseG1GC, -XX:G1ReservePercent=25, -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/opensearch-1034605652609818352, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=data, -XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m, -Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.threadFactory=org.opensearch.secure_sm.SecuredForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory, -Dclk.tck=100, -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true, -Djava.security.policy=/usr/share/opensearch/config/opensearch-performance-analyzer/opensearch_security.policy, --add-opens=jdk.attach/sun.tools.attach=ALL-UNNAMED, -Dopensearch.cgroups.hierarchy.override=/, -Xms4096m, -Xmx4096m, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=2147483648, -Dopensearch.path.home=/usr/share/opensearch, -Dopensearch.path.conf=/usr/share/opensearch/config, -Dopensearch.distribution.type=tar, -Dopensearch.bundled_jdk=true]
opensearch             | [2023-11-02T17:35:36,377][INFO ][o.o.s.s.t.SSLConfig      ] [05a295b38cbe] SSL dual mode is disabled
opensearch             | [2023-11-02T17:35:36,378][WARN ][o.o.s.OpenSearchSecurityPlugin] [05a295b38cbe] OpenSearch Security plugin installed but disabled. This can expose your configuration (including passwords) to the public.
opensearch             | [2023-11-02T17:35:36,688][INFO ][o.o.p.c.c.PluginSettings ] [05a295b38cbe] Config: metricsLocation: /dev/shm/performanceanalyzer/, metricsDeletionInterval: 1, httpsEnabled: false, cleanup-metrics-db-files: true, batch-metrics-retention-period-minutes: 7, rpc-port: 9650, webservice-port 9600
opensearch             | [2023-11-02T17:35:36,691][ERROR][o.o.p.c.PerformanceAnalyzerController] [05a295b38cbe] java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/share/opensearch/data/performance_analyzer_enabled.conf
opensearch             | java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/share/opensearch/data/performance_analyzer_enabled.conf
opensearch             |    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90) ~[?:?]
opensearch             |    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106) ~[?:?]
opensearch             |    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111) ~[?:?]
opensearch             |    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:218) ~[?:?]
opensearch             |    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:484) ~[?:?]
opensearch             |    at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:228) ~[?:?]
opensearch             |    at java.nio.file.Files.write(Files.java:3512) ~[?:?]
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.performanceanalyzer.config.PerformanceAnalyzerController.lambda$saveStateToConf$5(PerformanceAnalyzerController.java:335) [opensearch-performance-analyzer-2.11.0.0.jar:2.11.0.0]
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.performanceanalyzer.PerformanceAnalyzerPlugin.lambda$invokePrivileged$1(PerformanceAnalyzerPlugin.java:130) [opensearch-performance-analyzer-2.11.0.0.jar:2.11.0.0]
opensearch             |    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318) [?:?]
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.performanceanalyzer.PerformanceAnalyzerPlugin.invokePrivileged(PerformanceAnalyzerPlugin.java:126) [opensearch-performance-analyzer-2.11.0.0.jar:2.11.0.0]
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.performanceanalyzer.config.PerformanceAnalyzerController.saveStateToConf(PerformanceAnalyzerController.java:327) [opensearch-performance-analyzer-2.11.0.0.jar:2.11.0.0]
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.performanceanalyzer.config.PerformanceAnalyzerController.lambda$initPerformanceAnalyzerStateFromConf$0(PerformanceAnalyzerController.java:207) [opensearch-performance-analyzer-2.11.0.0.jar:2.11.0.0]
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.performanceanalyzer.PerformanceAnalyzerPlugin.lambda$invokePrivileged$1(PerformanceAnalyzerPlugin.java:130) [opensearch-performance-analyzer-2.11.0.0.jar:2.11.0.0]
opensearch             |    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318) [?:?]
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.performanceanalyzer.PerformanceAnalyzerPlugin.invokePrivileged(PerformanceAnalyzerPlugin.java:126) [opensearch-performance-analyzer-2.11.0.0.jar:2.11.0.0]
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.performanceanalyzer.config.PerformanceAnalyzerController.initPerformanceAnalyzerStateFromConf(PerformanceAnalyzerController.java:199) [opensearch-performance-analyzer-2.11.0.0.jar:2.11.0.0]
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.performanceanalyzer.config.PerformanceAnalyzerController.<init>(PerformanceAnalyzerController.java:55) [opensearch-performance-analyzer-2.11.0.0.jar:2.11.0.0]
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.performanceanalyzer.PerformanceAnalyzerPlugin.<init>(PerformanceAnalyzerPlugin.java:161) [opensearch-performance-analyzer-2.11.0.0.jar:2.11.0.0]
opensearch             |    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
opensearch             |    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
opensearch             |    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
opensearch             |    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[?:?]
opensearch             |    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[?:?]
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPlugin(PluginsService.java:782) [opensearch-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundle(PluginsService.java:731) [opensearch-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundles(PluginsService.java:533) [opensearch-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.plugins.PluginsService.<init>(PluginsService.java:195) [opensearch-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:480) [opensearch-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:407) [opensearch-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:242) [opensearch-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:242) [opensearch-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:404) [opensearch-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.bootstrap.OpenSearch.init(OpenSearch.java:180) [opensearch-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.bootstrap.OpenSearch.execute(OpenSearch.java:171) [opensearch-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:104) [opensearch-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:138) [opensearch-cli-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:101) [opensearch-cli-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.bootstrap.OpenSearch.main(OpenSearch.java:137) [opensearch-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
opensearch-dashboards  | Disabling OpenSearch Security Dashboards Plugin
opensearch-dashboards  | Removing securityDashboards...
opensearch-dashboards  | Plugin removal complete
opensearch-dashboards  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-11-02T17:35:36Z","tags":["info","plugins-service"],"pid":1,"message":"Plugin \"dataSourceManagement\" has been disabled since the following direct or transitive dependencies are missing or disabled: [dataSource]"}
opensearch-dashboards  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-11-02T17:35:36Z","tags":["info","plugins-service"],"pid":1,"message":"Plugin \"dataSource\" is disabled."}
opensearch-dashboards  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-11-02T17:35:36Z","tags":["info","plugins-service"],"pid":1,"message":"Plugin \"visTypeXy\" is disabled."}
opensearch-dashboards  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-11-02T17:35:36Z","tags":["warning","config","deprecation"],"pid":1,"message":"\"cpu.cgroup.path.override\" is deprecated and has been replaced by \"ops.cGroupOverrides.cpuPath\""}
opensearch-dashboards  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-11-02T17:35:36Z","tags":["warning","config","deprecation"],"pid":1,"message":"\"cpuacct.cgroup.path.override\" is deprecated and has been replaced by \"ops.cGroupOverrides.cpuAcctPath\""}
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.bootstrap.OpenSearch.main(OpenSearch.java:103) [opensearch-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
opensearch             | [2023-11-02T17:35:36,695][ERROR][o.o.p.c.PerformanceAnalyzerController] [05a295b38cbe] java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/share/opensearch/data/performance_analyzer_enabled.conf
opensearch             | java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/share/opensearch/data/performance_analyzer_enabled.conf
opensearch             |    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90) ~[?:?]
opensearch-dashboards  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-11-02T17:35:36Z","tags":["warning","config","deprecation"],"pid":1,"message":"\"opensearch.requestHeadersWhitelist\" is deprecated and has been replaced by \"opensearch.requestHeadersAllowlist\""}
opensearch-dashboards  | [agentkeepalive:deprecated] options.freeSocketKeepAliveTimeout is deprecated, please use options.freeSocketTimeout instead
opensearch-dashboards  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-11-02T17:35:36Z","tags":["info","plugins-system"],"pid":1,"message":"Setting up [50] plugins: [usageCollection,opensearchDashboardsUsageCollection,opensearchDashboardsLegacy,mapsLegacy,share,opensearchUiShared,legacyExport,embeddable,expressions,data,securityAnalyticsDashboards,home,apmOss,savedObjects,searchRelevanceDashboards,reportsDashboards,dashboard,mlCommonsDashboards,visualizations,visTypeVega,visTypeTimeline,visTypeTable,visTypeMarkdown,visBuilder,visAugmenter,anomalyDetectionDashboards,alertingDashboards,tileMap,regionMap,customImportMapDashboards,inputControlVis,ganttChartDashboards,visualize,queryWorkbenchDashboards,indexManagementDashboards,notificationsDashboards,management,indexPatternManagement,advancedSettings,console,dataExplorer,charts,visTypeVislib,visTypeTimeseries,visTypeTagcloud,visTypeMetric,observabilityDashboards,discover,savedObjectsManagement,bfetch]"}
opensearch             |    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106) ~[?:?]
opensearch-dashboards  | [agentkeepalive:deprecated] options.freeSocketKeepAliveTimeout is deprecated, please use options.freeSocketTimeout instead
opensearch             |    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111) ~[?:?]
opensearch-dashboards  | [agentkeepalive:deprecated] options.freeSocketKeepAliveTimeout is deprecated, please use options.freeSocketTimeout instead
opensearch             |    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:218) ~[?:?]
opensearch-dashboards  | [agentkeepalive:deprecated] options.freeSocketKeepAliveTimeout is deprecated, please use options.freeSocketTimeout instead
opensearch-dashboards  | [agentkeepalive:deprecated] options.freeSocketKeepAliveTimeout is deprecated, please use options.freeSocketTimeout instead
...
opensearch             | OpenSearchException[failed to bind service]; nested: AccessDeniedException[/usr/share/opensearch/data/nodes];
opensearch             | Likely root cause: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/share/opensearch/data/nodes
opensearch             |    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90)
opensearch             |    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)
opensearch             |    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
opensearch             |    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:397)
opensearch             |    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:700)
opensearch             |    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:807)
opensearch             |    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:793)
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.env.NodeEnvironment.lambda$new$0(NodeEnvironment.java:325)
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.env.NodeEnvironment$NodeLock.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:262)
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.env.NodeEnvironment.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:323)
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:525)
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:407)
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:242)
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:242)
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:404)
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.bootstrap.OpenSearch.init(OpenSearch.java:180)
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.bootstrap.OpenSearch.execute(OpenSearch.java:171)
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:104)
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:138)
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:101)
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.bootstrap.OpenSearch.main(OpenSearch.java:137)
opensearch             |    at org.opensearch.bootstrap.OpenSearch.main(OpenSearch.java:103)
opensearch             | For complete error details, refer to the log at /usr/share/opensearch/logs/docker-cluster.log
opensearch-dashboards  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-11-03T10:10:44Z","tags":["error","opensearch","data"],"pid":1,"message":"[ConnectionError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.19.0.2:9200"}
opensearch-dashboards  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-11-03T10:10:47Z","tags":["error","opensearch","data"],"pid":1,"message":"[ConnectionError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.19.0.2:9200"}
opensearch-dashboards  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-11-03T10:10:49Z","tags":["error","opensearch","data"],"pid":1,"message":"[ConnectionError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.19.0.2:9200"}
```

Я создал `/usr/share/opensearch/data/nodes` вручную, потому что он сказал, что я не могу получить к нему доступ, а его там не было. Я также выполнил команду `chmod +x /usr/share/opensearch/data/nodes`.